Why does AutoModel assign the XLMRobertaModel class to the model when I load E5?
Why does AutoModel assign the XLMRobertaModel class to the model when I load E5? Is E5 a separately trained XLMRobertaModel encoder? Will I lose knowledge of e5 when I initialize it like this?
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel, utils, AutoConfig
from bertviz import model_view
#from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

import pandas as pd
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("intfloat/multilingual-e5-large", output_attentions=True)


Explanation why this happens

Yes, it uses the XLM-Roberta architecture. Compare the config.
